# Why should be the resume and suspend methods be synchronized for a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

***I am not talking about the deprecated resume and suspend methods.*** Before I didn't use the synchronized keyword. I saw in a book that they used the synchronized keyword and I tried it and it worked perfectly. Can you explain me why this approach works and not using synchronized doesn't? Also why should while(suspendFlag) loop should be in the synchronized block too?

```
class myThread extends Thread {
boolean suspendFlag;    

    myThread(String name) {
        //some contructor
        suspendFlag = false;
    }

    public void run() {
       //simple loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            //do some thing
            synchronized(this){
                while (suspendFlag) {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized void resumeThread(){
        suspendFlag = false;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void suspendThread() {
        suspendFlag = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reason why you have synchronized just before your while loop is because of wait method as it needs to own the object's mutex before the call. [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) method as per the java doc says:

   > The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.
2. Why your code works with synchronization and not without:

   You might be accessing getter and setter method of same MyThread's object from multiple threads where one thread would read the value of suspendFlag while other might modify suspendFlag the value which might not be visible to the other thread and hence can create race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because the suspendFlag will be accessed from multiple threads, so the access to the suspendFlag must be sychronized, which means only one thread can access it at given moment.